# How many code lines do my project have

Tags: eclipse, code-metrics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Counting Line Numbers in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043666/counting-line-numbers-in-eclipse)

How Can I count the number of lines in my project including all the packages and projects in the Eclipse editor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use former Instantiations product [CodePro AnalytiX](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/download-codepro.html). This eclipse plugin provides you suchlike statistics in code metrics view. This is provided by Google free of charge.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check this Metrics2 plugin -

http://metrics2.sourceforge.net/

Comment: It seems this plugin supports only Java.