# Find number of lines in a project in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Is there a pluging/feature to count the number of lines in a project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counting Line Numbers in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043666/counting-line-numbers-in-eclipse)

Comment: Same question here check the answers:
[counting-line-numbers-in-eclipse][1]
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043666/counting-line-numbers-in-eclipse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for: http://metrics2.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Too bad Metrics only appears to be compatible with Eclipse 3.4/3.5 and I sure ain't rolling back from 4.2 :P

Answer (score 4):

A very simplistic way is to do a regular expression search for '\n' in your project. It will give you a good idea on the number of lines in your project without installing any extra plug-ins.

Comment: Indeed, and I thought about it. Maybe when I have more free time I'll get around to implementing one of my own, but for now I'm gonna have to go with metrics. It seems way more than I need but increbily useful. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of installing a new eclipse plugin; If you are on a linux system:

`cd` to the eclispe project source directory(workspace/project-name/src)

and enter in termianl:

`wc -l *.java`

This will show you total number of lines as well as number of lines in each file

Comment: it is pretty easy solution. also for recursive counting, "find . -name '*.java' | xargs wc -l" can be used

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to do it is based on this tutorial I found: http://stephendnicholas.com/posts/eclipse-quick-line-count

To summarize, do the following (to use search in Eclipse press **Ctrl+H**):

1. **Find the total amount of lines:** Search your code for `\n` using 'regular expression' under your code files (e.g. if you develop in java only then search only *.java files).
2. **Find the total amount of blank lines:** Search your code for `^\s*\n`
3. **Find the total amount of commented lines:** search your code for `//.*(\n{1})?`

**Finally:** Get the total amount of lines of code by subtracting 2 and 3 from 1.