# Counting number of code lines and classes in STS

Tags: java, eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Do you know any working plug-in for SpringSource Tool Suite 2.9.1 which will show me line-count and class-count for chosen project in workspace?

I know there's Metrics2 plug-in for Eclipse, but i found it not working with recent STS version ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1043666/913093)).

greetz

Comment: Just curious...what is the problem with getting the metrics plugin working in STS?

Comment: I've got Metrics view showing step-by-step instructions how to enable metrics (open java perspective, get package explorer view, build project etc.), but following them does nothing. There's a progress bar in the Metrics view, but it's always at 0% without any caption.

Answer (score 0):

With STS 3.6.4 it is working perfectly.
Make sure that:

1. You have selected the metrics view. Views-others.
2. Select Java perspective. Reset it if necessary to show the package structure.
3. In the project you want to analyze-properties-metrics-enable
4. Rebuild the project if it hasn't by itself...