# How to view the number of written lines in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I want to view how many lines there are in my program. I have searched everywhere in Eclipse and I can't seem to find how to do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043666/counting-line-numbers-in-eclipse You have searched in eclipse, but have you searched on Google or SO?!

Comment: Right click over the section where line number is appearing. Select "Show line number".

Answer (score 1):

Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors; select Show line numbers

Answer (score 0):

As user assylias already mentioned in a comment, there are some good [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043666/counting-line-numbers-in-eclipse) to this type of question.

User Vash's solution only shows the line number of the currently selected file.