# CodePro Analytix: Where to find the plugin

Tags: eclipse

I need to set up CodePro Analytix plugin . But  the link http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/codepro/latest/3.6 is not opening.

Please help me out. is there any other way to install CodePro Analytix or is there any other tools which does same functionality.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is an Eclipse update site, you can't open it in a web browser.

Instead you install it from Eclipse by opening 'Help > Install New Software...'. In the 'Work with:' field enter the update site URL for example `https://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/codepro/latest/3.7` which still works with Eclipse Oxygen.

Eclipse will then show you what can be installed from the update site.

Note: This code does not appear to have been updated for a while.

Comment: CodePro v3.7 exists and it still works with Eclipse Oxygen

Comment: @jett Sorry, thought it was clear enough because you just change the `/3.6` to a `/3.7` but here's actually a better idea. Just point to the latest: `http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/codepro/latest`

Comment: Unfortunately these links (including the `latest`) don't work anymore. Google didn't give me anything. Does somebody have an idea/link/whatever? :)

Answer (score 2):

You can install it from Eclipse Marketplace: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/codepro-analytix

But be careful, it's outdated and doesn't work with Juno or higher versions of Eclipse.

Comment: @CodeBlind I am running Neon and getting the following error: `This version of CodePro Analytix and PlusPak was compiled for Eclipse 3.7 but is running on Eclipse 3.12.`

Comment: I got a similarly-worded warning, but it did not prevent me from continuing. Ignoring it hasn't proved problematic for me over the months that I have used it this way.

Comment: Ok, let's say it isn't garanteed to work with versions later as Juno. And at some point, it will stop working.